# VueJs ,Vue.use(VueI18n) or app.use(VueI18n) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')

Tags: vuejs3

I use VueI18n but i have an error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
How con i solve this error?
Thnx?

```
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';
import { languages } from './i18n/index.js';
app.use(VueI18n);//here i have error

let locale = 'it';
```

const messages = Object.assign(languages);

export const i18n = new VueI18n({

```
locale: locale,

fallbackLocale: 'it',

messages,

i18n
```

});

Answer (score 1):

you have to create the application before using it :

main :

```
import App from './App.vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(VueI18n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where and what is your 'app'?
You can try this:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
const app = createApp({})
```

or

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
const app = createApp(App)
```

then

```
app.use(VueI18n)
```

Comment: My all code:
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

import { languages } from './i18n/index.js';
import { defaultFallbackLanguage } from './i18n/index.js';

const app = createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            base_url: process.env.MIX_APP_VUE_ROUTER_BASE
        }
    }
});

let locale = 'it';

const messages = Object.assign(languages);

export const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: locale,
    fallbackLocale: defaultFallbackLanguage,
    messages,
    i18n
})
app.use(VueI18n);

Comment: And error is
TypeError: vue_i18n__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default is not a constructor

Comment: This is usually a problem of  `import` syntax